# Is my matlab code solving the problem?

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I'm solving an assignment in numerical analysis where I use this model function for soundwaves under the water after fitting the model function in a least-squares sens and finding the coefficients.

$c(z)=4800+20.2090+(17.3368)\frac{z}{1000}+(272.9057)exp(-\frac{-0.7528z}{1000})$
and

$c'(z)=(-0.7528*272.9067/1000)exp(-\frac{-0.7528z}{1000})  +17.3368/1000$

Is the above correct? I get the expected answer ("You should ﬁnd that the depth at xf = 25 nautical miles is close to 2500 feet.") but the graph doesn't look as expected. It seems to indicate that the sound wave is moving down, then up and then down again. Could it be correct or is there mistakenly done?

> Since the sound speed varies with depth, sound rays will travel
>   in curved paths. A ﬁxed underwater point emits rays in all directions.
>   Given a particular point and initial direction we would like to follow
>   the ray path. Thus letting x be the horizontal coordinate we know the
>   initial values: x = 0, z = z0, dz=dx = tan 0, where 0 denotes the
>   angle between the horizontal line z = z0 and the ray in the start
>   point.

I got some help at scicomp https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/8346/ode45-usage-in-this-case but I'm not sure about the solution.

[image]

> The ray path z(x) is described by the following second order
>   diﬀerential equation

$\displaystyle\frac{d^2z}{dx^2}= \frac{-q_0c'(z)}{c(z)^3}$

where $\displaystyle q_0 = \left(\frac{c(z_0)}{\cos b_0}\right)^2$

> Use the Runge-Kutta method (or ode45) to trace the ray beginning at z0
>   = 2000 feet and b0 = 7.8 degrees. Follow the ray for 25 nautical miles (1 nautical mile is 6076 feet). Plot the curve z(x). You should
>   ﬁnd that the depth at xf = 25 nautical miles is close to 2500 feet.
>
> Now suppose that a sound source at a depth of 2000 feet transmits to a
>   receiver 25 miles away at a depth of 2500 feet. The above calculation
>   shows that one of the rays from the source to the receiver leaves the
>   source at an angle close to 7.8 degrees. Because of the nonlinearity
>   of the equation there may be other rays leaving at diﬀerent angles
>   that reach the same receiver. Run your program for b0 in the range
>   from 10 up to 14 degrees, plot the ray paths and print a table of the
>   values z(xf).
>
> We are interested in ﬁnding values of 0 for which z(xf) = 2500. Use
>   an eﬃcient algorithm to determine the rays which pass through the
>   receiver. Discuss the accuracy of your results.

```
 function dZ=sys(x,Z)
    c=@(z)4800 + 20.2090 + (17.3368)*z/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-z*0.7528/1000); % c(z)
    c=c(2000);

% Z(1):=z
% Z(2):=u
    dZ=zeros(2,1);    % a column vector
    dZ(1)=Z(2);
    dZ(2)=-(c/cosd(7.8))^2*(((-272.9057*0.7528/1000)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000)) + 17.3368/1000)/...
        (4800 + 20.2090 + (17.3368)*Z(1)/1000+ (272.9057)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000))^3;
    end
```

I ran the above code with the script

```
x=0:0.5:6076*25;
[X,Z]=ode45(@sys,x,[2000 tand(7.8)]);
plot(X,Z(:,1),'r')
```

Then I get this graph which actually has the correct value (2500) at 25 nautical miles. Is the solution correct? Then I iterate over initial values to find which go to the receiver. Could that be feasible?

```
hold on
x=0:5:6076*25;
for i=-10:14
[X,Z]=ode45(@sys,x,[2000 tand(i)]);
plot(X,Z(:,1),'r')  %Z(:,1) is z(x) and Z(:,2) is z'(x).
i=i+1;
end

hold off
```

Comment: It looks like you are dealing with the deep sound channel, which traps sound projected at suitable angle in the way your plot shows. However the sound speed profile you give is wrong for the kind of ducting your plot shows. You probably have a sign error in the exp function (the double negative should be a single negative?), with the corrected form in your code it gives a sound speed profile consistent with the ray bending in your plot.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I wrote the derivate like this `(-272.9057*0.7528/1000)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000)) + 17.3368/1000` Do you think it's wrong and that it has a sign error? I'm not sure what that should be. Please inform me what can be the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but it is too long for a comment.

First, your double minus sign making a problem to me, I started from your data and fitted, just as you did, the model $$c(z)=4800+a+\frac{b z}{1000}+c e^{\frac{d z}{1000}}$$ and obtained $a=-20.209$ (**not** $+20.209$), $b=17.3368$, $c=272.906$, $d=-0.752778$ and the fit is effectively very good.

Concerning the derivative, it write $$c'(z)=\frac{1}{1000}\Big(b+c\, d \,e^{\frac{d z}{1000}}\Big)$$ and it only cancels once at  $$z_{*}=\frac{1000 }{d}\log \left(-\frac{b}{c d}\right)$$ ($3284$ using the numbers); so $c(z)$ decreases for $0<z<z_{*}$ and increases for $z_{*}<z$; it never decreases again.

Comment: Thank you for the information. But I don't fully understand how you write the derivative. Should it not be differentiated term by term?

Comment: Yes, this is how I did. Afterwords, I factored the $\frac{1}{10000}$; that's it.

Comment: I have written my derivative like this `(-272.9057*0.7528/1000)*exp(-Z(1)*0.7528/1000)) + 17.3368/1000` is it incorrect? I'm sorry that I don't understand what can be wrong.

Comment: This seems to be correct.